# Read excel sheet with multiple header using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have an excel sheet with multiple header like:

```
_________________________________________________________________________
    ____|_____|        Header1    |        Header2     |        Header3      |
    ColX|ColY |ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD||ColD|ColE|ColF|ColG||ColH|ColI|ColJ|ColDK|
    1   | ds  | 5  | 6  |9   |10  | .......................................
    2   | dh  |  ..........................................................
    3   | ge  |  ..........................................................
    4   | ew  |  ..........................................................
    5   | er  |  ..........................................................
```

Now here you can see that first two columns do not have headers they are blank but other columns have headers like Header1, Header2 and Header3. So I want to read this sheet and merge it with other sheet with similar structure.

I want to merge it on first column 'ColX'. Right now I am doing this:

```py
import pandas as pd

totalMergedSheet = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5], columns=['ColX'])
file = pd.ExcelFile('ExcelFile.xlsx')
for i in range (1, len(file.sheet_names)):
    df1 = file.parse(file.sheet_names[i-1])
    df2 = file.parse(file.sheet_names[i])
    newMergedSheet = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ColX')
    totalMergedSheet = pd.merge(totalMergedSheet, newMergedSheet, on='ColX')
```

But I don't know its neither reading columns correctly and I think will not return the results in the way I want. So, I want the resulting frame should be like:

```
________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    ____|_____|        Header1    |        Header2     |        Header3      |        Header4     |        Header5      |
    ColX|ColY |ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD||ColD|ColE|ColF|ColG||ColH|ColI|ColJ|ColK| ColL|ColM|ColN|ColO||ColP|ColQ|ColR|ColS|
    1   | ds  | 5  | 6  |9   |10  | ..................................................................................
    2   | dh  |  ...................................................................................
    3   | ge  |  ....................................................................................
    4   | ew  |  ...................................................................................
    5   | er  |  ......................................................................................
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[See comments for updates and corrections]

Pandas already has a function that will read in an entire Excel spreadsheet for you, so you don't need to manually parse/merge each sheet. Take a look [pandas.read_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html). It not only lets you read in an Excel file in a single line, it also provides options to help solve the problem you're having.

Since you have subcolumns, what you're looking for is [MultiIndexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html). By default, pandas will read in the top row as the sole header row. You can pass a `header` argument into `pandas.read_excel()` that indicates how many rows are to be used as headers. In your particular case, you'd want `header=[0, 1]`, indicating the first two rows. You might also have multiple sheets, so you can pass `sheetname=None` as well (this tells it to go through all sheets). The command would be:

```
df_dict = pandas.read_excel('ExcelFile.xlsx', header=[0, 1], sheetname=None)
```

This returns a dictionary where the keys are the sheet names, and the values are the DataFrames for each sheet. If you want to collapse it all into one DataFrame, you can simply use pandas.concat:

```
df = pandas.concat(df_dict.values(), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, indices are MultiIndex too (it is indeed the case in the OP). To account for that, pass the `index_col=` appropriately.

```py
df_dict = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', header=[0,1], index_col=[0,1], sheetname=None)
```